# How to use variables from one class in other classes?

Tags: java, class, variables

How can I use variables from one class in my other classes? For example, I have

Class 1

```
public class maintype {
    public int A = 1,
               B = 2,
               C = 3,
               D = 4;

    public String E, F, G

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    }
}
```

Class 2

```
public class subclass {
    public numbers() {
        AB = A + B;
    }
}
```

I want to use the variable a and b in my second class but it is giving me an error. saying no such variable exist but I don't want to create that variable again in my second class.

Comment: `public class subclass extends maintype`?

Comment: read some doc.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: You will also need to declare the field AB in your subclass: private int AB;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to extend

```
  public class subclass extends maintype{
        public numbers(){
         AB = A+B;
        }
        }
```

Comment: oh ye, thanks. btw is there any other way? and also is it possible to extend my class 1 to in class 2 and my class 2 to class 1?

Comment: @user3288493 I'm almost positive you can't have two classes extend each other. If you're trying to do that, it's a sign that you probably should take a step back and rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the class as in::

```
    public class subclass extends maintype{
    public numbers(){
     AB = A+B;
    }
   }
```

This is the common feature of java Called **Inheritance**, Explained below::

**Definitions:** A class that is derived from another class is called a subclass (also a derived class, extended class, or child class). The class from which the subclass is derived is called a superclass (also a base class or a parent class).

Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.

Classes can be derived from classes that are derived from classes that are derived from classes, and so on, and ultimately derived from the topmost class, Object. Such a class is said to be descended from all the classes in the inheritance chain stretching back to Object.

*For more details follow this link::*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `extends` keyword in `subclass`, so I have corrected it for you.

Superclass:

```
    public class superclass{
    public static int A = 1;
    public static int B = 2;
    public static int C = 3;
    public static int D = 4;

    public String str1 = "E";
    public String str2 = "F";
    public String str3 = "G";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //What do you want to put here?
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class subclass extends superclass {
     public void numbers(){
        int A = superclass.A;
        int B = superclass.B;
        int AB = A + B;
    }
}
```